# How to write an attribute value along with ngModel

Tags: angularjs

How to put some additional value with ngModel

If I have an html

```
<select ng-model="forms.options" data-custom-select="">
<option value="value1" data-special-value="reference1">Value 1</option>
<option value="value2" data-special-value="reference2">Value 2</option>
<option value="value3" data-special-value="reference3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

and a custom directive "customSelect" with requires ngModel

I'm expecting a value on ngModel

```
{value:<Selected Value>,reference:<data-special-value>}
```

Is this really possible?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, what you are trying to do  or why you need data attributes on `<option>`. Should be able to do everything you need using `ng-options`

Comment: you can do it even without custom directive using `ng-change="selected(reference1)"` and do some code in controller

Comment: want to make this a directive/component to repeat logic

Answer (score 1):

**You can add the `object` directly into `ng-options` and get your result in the selected modal.**

**using ng-options:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="option.value for option in options" ng-change="selected(option.reference)">
</select><br>
Selected Value: {{selectedName}}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = [
{ value: 'value1', reference: 'reference1' },
{ value: 'value2', reference: 'reference2' },
{ value: 'value3', reference: 'reference3' }, 
]

});
</script>

<p>Select a value from dropdown.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NQ9bjM1spJhZLPujPjHM?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But not able to use ng-options since this was a rendered HTML